# Determine new unique entries for date range in table where an item can appear multiple times

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a MySQL database (InnoDB engine) which over time, tracks visits of a user to a specific item:

**Table format**:

```
(pk) item_id: bigint
(pk) date: date
     user_id: bigint
```

Visits by the same user can appear multiple times in this table and the table can have several hundred million rows quite easily (several thousand per item).

As the table is item and date clustered, it's quite fast to query date ranges for charting, but I would also like to determine *which users appeared for the first time in a date range*.

How can I do this efficiently?

**Sample data**:

```
item_id | date       | user_id
---------------------------------
1       | 2000-01-01 | 2
1       | 2000-01-02 | 1
1       | 2000-01-03 | 3
1       | 2000-01-04 | 4
1       | 2000-01-05 | 1
1       | 2000-01-06 | 3
```

**Selecting new users since *2000-01-03* on item *1* should return**:

```
3, 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This seems to work](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef73a/4) as `GROUP BY` selects the first occurrence (in MySQL at least). This allows me to determine the first time the user was seen:

```
SELECT user_id, date
FROM user_track
WHERE item_id = 1
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING date >= '2000-01-03';
```

Answer (score 0):

With the assumption whether the user have appeared outside the time range is not of a concern, I would use the following query:

```
select
    user_id,
    count(user_id) as visit_count
from
    cn_order where date between "$start_timerange" and "$end_timerange"
group by
        user_id having(visit_count) < 2;
```

and if item is also of importance, add "and item_id = '$item_id'" to the filtering clause

Comment: Unfortunately, the user occurrence must be global to the item, not within the specific date range.